# how to make sure whether this number is reasonable to pick the exceptional value out?

Tags: statistics, threshold

As the title said, now I have a group random values from 1 to 3000. And I have a threshold 412.53. I want to know how to make sure this number can be threshold like normal distribution or any other statistics methods to pick some exceptional values like 2951(one value in this group) and so on.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Identifying_outliers

Comment: You mean using these method to check my group values directly, not using threshold?